# How to distinguish the results from python future?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I am trying to upload 2 files to some URL. The method signature is as below:

```
def upload_file(file_path):
    ...
    return some_value
```

Now, I am calling using this method as below:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(upload_file,file_path=path_1),
               executor.submit(upload_file,file_path=path_2)]

for future in as_completed(futures):
    log.info(f'Future completed: {future.result()}')
```

This is working as expected.
However, I would like to store the results from 2 futures in different variables.
How do I achieve that i.e. How do I distinguish the results of 2 futures?

Answer (score 0):

Use your previous array:

```
results = [future.results() for future in futures]
```

Though this line won't finish executing until all futures have returned, so you may want to add an optional timeout (in seconds):

```
results = [future.results(timeout=60) for future in futures]
```

Comment: How do I know which result is from which future? Do I need to change way I am handling the futures?

Comment: If you need to know, which future it came from use your original futures list. I've added an example for reference.